# Pandas reshape sets of columns as rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

```
A1 B1 C1 A4 B4 C4 A7 B7 C7
A2 B2 C2 A5 B5 C5 A8 B8 C8
A3 B3 C3 A6 B6 C6 A9 B9 C9
```

that I would like to get looking like this:

```
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
A4 B4 C4
A5 B5 C5
A6 B6 C6
A7 B7 C7
A8 B8 C8
A9 B9 C9
```

Is there anything built into pandas or another data processing library that can easily do this without manually traversing the rows 3 (in this example) times for each "column set"? This would essentially be a 3-column pivot.

Comment: you can do `df.values.reshape(-1,3)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang check his ordering of output, reshape won't cut it

Answer (score 2):

### `reshape` + `swapaxes` + `reshape`

---

```
df.values.reshape(-1, 3, 3).swapaxes(1, 0).reshape(-1, 3)
```

```
array([['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
       ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'],
       ['A3', 'B3', 'C3'],
       ['A4', 'B4', 'C4'],
       ['A5', 'B5', 'C5'],
       ['A6', 'B6', 'C6'],
       ['A7', 'B7', 'C7'],
       ['A8', 'B8', 'C8'],
       ['A9', 'B9', 'C9']], dtype=object)
```

---

To expand this and make it more general, you can calculate your offsets based on your grouping, For example, let's say group every 4 columns in the following Frame:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 A4 B4 C4 D4 A7 B7 C7 D7
A2 B2 C2 D2 A5 B5 C5 D5 A8 B8 C8 D8
A3 B3 C3 D3 A6 B6 C6 D6 A9 B9 C9 D9

n = 4
f = df.shape[1] // n

df.values.reshape(-1, f, n).swapaxes(1, 0).reshape(-1, n)
```

```
array([['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
       ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
       ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3'],
       ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'],
       ['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5'],
       ['A6', 'B6', 'C6', 'D6'],
       ['A7', 'B7', 'C7', 'D7'],
       ['A8', 'B8', 'C8', 'D8'],
       ['A9', 'B9', 'C9', 'D9']], dtype=object)
```

---

Using the underlying array is going to be quite a fast approach.

```
df = pd.concat([df]*500)

In [128]: %%timeit
     ...: n = 3
     ...: f = df.shape[1] // n
     ...: df.values.reshape(-1, f, n).swapaxes(1, 0).reshape(-1, n)
     ...:
77.4 µs ± 417 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [129]: %%timeit
     ...: c = np.arange(len(df.columns))
     ...: df.columns = [c // 3, c % 3]
     ...: df1 = df.stack(0).sort_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
     ...:
     ...:
12.2 ms ± 326 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `MultiIndex` created by modulo and integer division:

```py
c = np.arange(len(df.columns))

df.columns = [c // 3, c % 3]
df1 = df.stack(0).sort_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
    0   1   2
0  A1  B1  C1
1  A2  B2  C2
2  A3  B3  C3
3  A4  B4  C4
4  A5  B5  C5
5  A6  B6  C6
6  A7  B7  C7
7  A8  B8  C8
8  A9  B9  C9
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really experienced in pandas so I don't know the exact syntax. But you could split the original dataframe into 3 chunks and then re-concatenate into your desired dataframe along the 1st axis.

So it could be separated into

```
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
```

,

```
A4 B4 C4
A5 B5 C5
A6 B6 C6
```

,

```
A7 B7 C7
A8 B8 C8
A9 B9 C9
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You could reconstruct the df:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

letters = sorted(set(j for i in chain(*df.values) for j in i if j.isalpha()))
v = {letter: sorted(i for i in chain(*df.values) if i.startswith(letter)) for letter in letters}

dff = pd.DataFrame(v)
print(dff)

    A   B   C
0  A1  B1  C1
1  A2  B2  C2
2  A3  B3  C3
3  A4  B4  C4
4  A5  B5  C5
5  A6  B6  C6
6  A7  B7  C7
7  A8  B8  C8
8  A9  B9  C9
```